# Google +1 Button not showing on all posts on Tumblr (endless scroll enabled)

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

When I have endless scroll enabled on my Tumblr blog.fokus.org my Google +1 button does not show when posts are after Page 2. If I disable endless scroll then it shows up on each page correctly. Ideally, I want to have endless scroll on.

When you click into a post to open the link to the post it shows all the buttons fine regardless of what page it is on (with or without endless scroll enabled).

This is for a post that falls after the Page 2, which has the following code:

```
<hr class="tumblrAutoPager_page_separator">
<div class="tumblrAutoPager_page_info">
```

I used the Firebug console and noticed the difference is with how the code is being loaded.

post on page1

```
<div id="___plusone_0" style="height: 20px; width: 90px; display: inline-block; text-indent: 0pt; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; border-style: none; float: none; line-height: normal; font-size: 1px; vertical-align: baseline;">
```

which has iframe code in it as well

post on page2 only shows this code

```
<g:plusone href="http://blog.fokus.org/post/16268298715/sirinthada-make-lots-of-art-listen-to-music" width="100" size="medium"></g:plusone>
```

The code I have entered
in the metadata section

```
<g:plusone size="medium"  width="100" href="{Permalink}"></g:plusone>
```

and at the end of the code before

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the page finishes loading all the `<g:pluseone />`'s on the page get rendered into +1 buttons. When a new page loads you have the `<g:pluseone />`'s in the HTML but you have to use the [+1 JSAPI](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#jsapi) to turn them into buttons.

Something like the following will need to get called every page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  gapi.plusone.go("body");
</script>
```

For performance you should change `body` to be more specific.

Comment: i went with the iframe route as this seems to be the only one that didn't cause any issues. 

Thank you for the reply!